# Make js.erb file to work without ajax Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a view 

**index.html.erb** ->
`link_to "click me " , 'customers/index' , :remote => true` .

**controller -> customers**

```
def index
end
```

**index.js.erb**

```
alert('in js file');
```

`alert` works absolutely fine . but what if i don't want to make ajax and i just want js.erb file to work every time customers/index is loaded . I'm new to `rails` development and my question may very basic but i could not find a solution . I know that we specify the following when we want specific type . but as far i know my case is differenct

```
respond_to do |format|
format.js
format.html
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply move the code from `index.js.erb` to `index.html.erb`.

If you want to keep it separately then you could move js code to a partial and render it inside `index.html.erb`. See docs [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials).

**Update**

How to do this with partial:

1. Create `_yourpartial.js.erb` and fill with js code
2. To render the code inside 'index.html.erb' add this: `<%= render partial: 'yourpartial', formats: [:js] %>`

(But of course you would still need the script tag around the js code)

Comment: Don't you enjoy the beauty of `js.erb` partial? :)

Comment: I mean create `_yourpartial.js.erb` and render it inside the `index.html.erb`

Comment: @ImranNaqvi, have you checked my updated answer? If it appears like a text then you just forgot to add `script` tags

Comment: yeah you're right but we don't need to specify the format , just specify .js.erb with the partial as `render partial: 'yourpartial.js.erb'`

Answer (score -1):

I'd try to help you. You can put your ajax into your `application.js`. For make it clean, you have to create one function into document ready. Document ready function will be active when the page have already done to load.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    callAjaxCustomerIndex(location.pathname);
});

function callAjaxCustomerIndex(current_url) {
  if (current_url == "/customers")
    $.ajax({
        url: "/customers",
        async: false,
        method: "GET",
        data: { "place_id" : place["place_id"] },
        success: function(data){
                 alert('success');
             }
         });
         infoWindow.open(map, marker);
         buildIWContent(place);
    });
}
```

This ajax request will be send when `location.pathname` is "customers". I hope this help you.

Comment: I think you didn't noticed the question . I clearly stated that I want js.erb to work **without** ajax